# How to express a rank-2 tensor as a spherical tensor?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus, spherical-harmonics

A common example how to write a rank-2 tensor in the spherical basis is an outer product of two vectors, 
$$ T_{ij} = a_i b_j $$
such that 
$$ T_{ij} = \frac{\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}}{3}\delta_{ij} + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}(\textbf{a}\times\textbf{b})_k + \left( \frac{a_ib_j+a_jb_i}{2}-\frac{\textbf{a}\cdot\textbf{b}}{3}\delta_{ij} \right) $$
gives a decomposition into a rank-0, rank-1 and rank-2 tensor (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_operator#Spherical_tensor_operators))

$$\begin{align}
T^{(2)}_{\pm 2} &= a_{\pm 1} b_{\pm 1} \\ 
{T}^{(2)}_{\pm 1} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( {a}_{\pm 1} {b}_0 + {a}_0 {b}_{\pm 1} \right) \\
{T}^{(2)}_{0} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\left( {a}_{+1} {b}_{-1} + {a}_{-1} {b}_{+1} + 2 {a}_0 {b}_0 \right)
\end{align}$$

Using $a_\pm = \mp (a_x\pm \text{i} a_y)/\sqrt 2$ and $a_0=a_z$, we can write e.g. $T^{(2)}_{+2}$ as 
$$ T^{(2)}_{+2} = \frac{1}{2}[a_xb_x-a_yb_y+\text{i}(a_xb_y+a_yb_x)] $$

My question is as follows:

> For a general rank-2 tensor $S_{ij}$ with components $S_{xx}$, $S_{xy}$, etc., can we get the spherical tensor by replacing $a_ib_j\mapsto S_{ij}$?

This would lead to 
$$ S^{(2)}_{+2} = \frac{1}{2}[S_{xx}-S_{yy}+\text{i}(S_{xy}+S_{yx})] $$

Comment: Hitting the Cartesian tensor on both sides with [U and conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_basis#Change_of_basis_matrix), respectively, to change basis is unclear?

Comment: It's not that it's unclear, it's just unhelpful.

Comment: ? So you are happy and yawning with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_operator#Spherical_tensor_operators) and want the generic expression for a generic *S*? Do you add spins with arrows in your sleep?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I don't understand your hostile attitude. If you have something to contribute, then I would be more than happy to read an answer post instead of a half-hearted comment. If not, then not. Your method of multiplying U just yields a 3x3 matrix again, where it's not clear how to extract the q=-2,...,2 components.

Comment: ? I am not being hostile, by any means. I am inviting you to *explain* what you believe the problem is. It is a change of basis. Had you written your generic *S* in that basis, I could grasp what it is you are after. I just *asked* you if you are comfortable with the WP section linked and you are asking to move on beyond that.  In your case, it is the addition of two spin triplets to a spin 2, 1, and 0. But I can't start perorating on an "answer" idly hoping that it might hit the spot. It *is* rude to expect your mind read and complain when it is not.

Comment: The Clebsch series of a rank 2-tensor reduces to a singlet, a triplet, and a quintet, which you have already  done in the Cartesian basis. In the spherical basis, the addition of spins is manifest (this is the bit about the arrow addition algorithm in your sleep).

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining your comments. I tried to edit my question as precise and narrow as possible.

Comment: For the scalar and spin 2 you symmetrize a and b, for the spin 1 you antisymmetrize.  Your final “leads to” equation appears right.

Comment: And lest I left it unsaid, the answer to your revised question is "yes": the dyadic is a good transformation prototype/simulator of a generic rank two tensor. You are only interested in transformation of your indices under rotations, here.

Comment: I understand. Thank you!